# include only attributes of a record which are not null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlbulkcopy

Dear people from stackoverflow

I'm currently working on a mechanism to export data out of a database. Every record  has roughly 30 attributes and I only want to export those attributes which do have an actual value.

If the explanation is not precise enough, here's an example:

```
+----+-----------+------------+---------+--------+
| ID | Name      | Profession | Country | Salary |
+----+-----------+------------+---------+--------+
| 1  | John Doe  | NULL       | USA     | 5000   |
+----+-----------+------------+---------+--------+
| 2  | Jane Doe  | Painter    | NULL    | NULL   |
+----+-----------+------------+---------+--------+
| 3  | Jonas Doe | Butcher    | England | 8000   |
+----+-----------+------------+---------+--------+

Expected outputs:
John Doe: John Doe, USA, 5000
Jane Doe: Jane Doe, Painter
Jonas Doe: Jonas Doe, Butcher, England, 8000
```

These outputs should be generated in an XML file.

This should be possible with every record in the database if possible. 
I was looking for a function that would check if an attribute has a value and depending on that, adds it to the export file or not. Sadly I couldn't find anything like that.

Edit:
What i did until now is just writing the query to get all the possible attributes:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE export @id int AS
BEGIN
SELECT Name,Profession,Country,Salary FROM Employee
WHERE ID = @id;
END
GO
```

Comment: select   Name, concat(Name,',', Profession ,',', Country,',',Salary) from table

Comment: I was thinking about this too, but the export format should be in an xml format if possible... So i don't really know how to apply for that.

Comment: Then update your question to show what really are you after. You can simply add `FOR XML`.

Comment: you can convert comma separated value  to XML also but please post what you want...

Comment: Did so, thanks you very much. I'll give it a try and let you know how it worked out

Comment: by removing NULLs from your CSV, you are also losing the context of what the thing is - so it might become hard to know if a column referred to profession or country.  So if the entry was simply 'Chad' is he called Chad, or from the country Chad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just select everything from the table you want, using `FOR XML PATH`.

```
WITH Employee (ID, [Name], Profession, Country, Salary) AS (
SELECT 1, 'John Doe', NULL, 'USA', 5000 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Jane Doe', 'Painter', NULL, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Jonas Doe', 'Butcher', 'England', 8000
)

SELECT *
FROM Employee
FOR XML PATH
```

would return

```
<row>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Name>John Doe</Name>
  <Country>USA</Country>
  <Salary>5000</Salary>
</row>
<row>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <Name>Jane Doe</Name>
  <Profession>Painter</Profession>
</row>
<row>
  <ID>3</ID>
  <Name>Jonas Doe</Name>
  <Profession>Butcher</Profession>
  <Country>England</Country>
  <Salary>8000</Salary>
</row>
```

**EDIT**

```
WITH Employee (ID, [Name], Profession, Country, Salary) AS (
SELECT 1, 'John Doe', NULL, 'USA', 5000 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Jane Doe', 'Painter', NULL, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Jonas Doe', 'Butcher', 'England', 8000
)

SELECT ID, (SELECT * FROM Employee S WHERE S.ID = M.ID FOR XML PATH) [XML]
FROM Employee M
```

Would return a row per `ID` with it's `XML` data.

Comment: That seems pretty straight forward, but sadly I need to get a file per record. I appreciate your answer though! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @capojere You could generate a row per ID returning `XML` for each ID, which would at least provide you with the data needed to generate the files.